# Firefox extension missing Referer url in ajax header when making ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to make an ajax call to a server and the server needs referer url to identify my request

```
    $.ajax({        
            url: abc + '/123/xyz/',
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                    "key": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                }
            }).done(function(result) {
                executeOnSuccess();
    });
```

The expected result on the server should be that if i execute this line  `request.getHeader("referer");`

I should get the referer url but i get a null, but if i make the same ajax request using chrome extension it works and i get the referer url.

I have been stuck on this for a while now. The other option is to add referer url manually to the ajax header but i was expecting it to work like chrome?

Does any one has any idea about it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact URL and protocol you are making the request from?

Comment: Well I can't give the exact url, but what i can tell you is that i tried with both protocols http and https and in either case the referer url is not there is the request header.

Comment: Important consideration: where is that code called from? Content script or otherwise?

Comment: @Xan This code is called from Firefox extension

Comment: @Osama.070032 _Which part_ of the extension?

Comment: @Xan The part which injects script to an html page.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will always overwrite the referrer. Meaning you can't change the referrer of an ajax call.  But you can try!

```
$.ajax({
    url: abc + '/123/xyz/',
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Referer": "Change here reference"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Also, note that if you are planning to submit your extension in AMO, you should always use *https* in your calls to any server.

Comment: Well if i ran the same code on a chrome browser it will send the referrer in the header automatically, where as in Firefox it doesn't work that way i have to send it manually like you pointed out in the above example. So is it a common Firefox behaviour or am i missing something. Just to be clear this ajax call is being called from an extension created for Firefox and chrome.